# Amplify sinusoïdal signal with op-amp with V- = 0V

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have a small sinusoidal signal, with an amplitude of 10 mV (the signal goes from -5mV to 5mV) that I'd like to amplify.

I'd like to use an op amp, but my problem is that I only have +3V and GND voltages to supply the op amp. Which means the classical amplifying circuit would not work:

[image]

Any idea how I could amplify my input signal?

Comment: Normally you'd AC-couple it into a supply divider, but the signal is so low that it could easily get lost in the PSU noise. How clean is the supply?

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? Signal comes from an excited piezo transducer.

Comment: How clean is your power supply voltage. Is the noise on the power supply < 1mV? The simple solution is to put a small series capacitor and then use two resistors to set the DC voltage on Vin to about 1.5V. But if you have a noisy power supply then all you will amplify is the power supply noise.

Comment: Power supply is a 3V battery. I thought about shifting of 1.5V the Vin, but the 1.5V offset is going to be amplified too, am I right?

Comment: @Vincz777 Not if you set your op-amp V- to 0v and V+ to +3v. That's called floating ground -- it makes the opamp operate "as if" ground was at +1.5V.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **basic circuit** just needs a few extra components.

[image]

Adding C2 gives it a DC gain of 1 but keeps the AC gain set by Rf,Rg  (G= 1+ Rf/Rg)

Adding R1,R2 creates the mid point DC offset at the non inverting input.

Adding R3 and C4 creates a smoothed supply (low pass filter) for this offset.

Adding C1 decouples the input.

Adding C3 decouples the output

*Additional edit*

R3 and C4 ensure that the voltage to the potential divider (R1,R2) is as noise free as possible. Any noise on the potential divider would appear at the (non-inverting) input and be amplified.

*With regard to values:*

R3 was chosen to be less than 1% of R1,R2 so that it would not drop too much voltage before the potential divider. C4 value was chosen because it is a commonly used value and gives a low break frequency .

These values are not particularly critical and others could be substituted if needed

Comment: P.S. Be careful about capacitor types. You may want to use a film capacitor for C1 to avoid microphonic effects (though if you are using the circuit as a microphone amplifier anyway that may not matter so much).

Comment: Is R3 supposed to say 10k instead of 1k0?

Comment: @Brian the prefix is used like a decimal point, so `1k0` means `1.0k`.

Comment: @2012rcampion Thank you, I didn't know whether that was a typo or just a notation I wasn't familiar with.  I haven't seen 1k written as 1k0 before.

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion I confirm that 1k0 is 1000 Ohms.

Comment: Why is the low pass filter created by R3 and C4 necessary? And how does one choose their values?

Comment: @Hamsteriffic R3 and C4 ensure that the voltage to the potential divider (R1,R2) is as noise free as possible. Any noise on the potential divider would appear at the (non-inverting) input and be amplified.  With regard to values R3 was chosen to be less than 1% of R1,R2 so that it would not drop too much voltage before the potential divider. C4 value was chosen because it is a commonly used value and gives a low break frequency . These values are not particularly critical and others could be substituted if needed.

Comment: @JImDearden Thanks for the explanation. I think you should add that to the answer (since comments aren't guaranteed to last long), I feel that it adds a lot to it. Copy-pasting is probably enough.